# MySQL OFFSET with WHERE clause condition is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
WHERE site_code = "TT" AND delete_flag = 'n'
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 5;
```

The problem is the results is not accurate. I got results where "site_code" is not "TT". My question is, is it possible to use OFFSET with WHERE condition?

Comment: Your query cannot return rows where `site_code` is not `'TT'`.

Comment: yes. thats my point. the problem is it only follows the OFFSET regardless even if site_code is 'TT' or not.

Comment: Unless you have a column named `TT` in the table.

Comment: Can you reproduce this sharing an **sql fiddle**?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you are trying to say the results are logically valid but it's not the specific rows you expect. Specifying `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is not going to give you a deterministic set of rows, whether or not you include `OFFSET`, but the rows returned should all still match the conditions in `WHERE`.  Please clarify the problem.  If you are saying this query returns rows with "site_code" set to a value other than "TT" then you have somehow introduced index corruption into your table.

Comment: You're right @Michael-sqlbot. that solves my problem. Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it as a solution to my question

Answer (score 0):

Rows in a table do not have a defined order.  When `LIMIT x` is used, the server will return exactly `x` matching rows, but *which* `x` rows is undefined.  With `OFFSET y` the first row returned is offset by `y` from the first row that might otherwise have been returned, but -- with or without a specified `OFFSET`, in SQL, there is no defined "first" row.

The rows are an unordered set, so *which* specific rows will be returned is also undefined unless `ORDER BY` is also specified.

The only constraint, otherwise, is that `x` rows will be returned (if that many matching rows exist) and that they will match `WHERE` -- but *which* rows are returned is otherwise essentially whichever rows the optimizer finds first, using whatever criteria it chooses for matching rows against the selection criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use in this way
Example:

SELECT
employee_id, first_name, last_name, salary
FROM
employees
WHERE
salary = (SELECT DISTINCT
salary
FROM
employees
ORDER BY salary DESC
LIMIT 1 , 1);